# CSS Text Centering for absolutely positioned divs

Tags: css, html, centering, absolute

I've read most similar posts, but neither using line-height equal to height or display:table-cell + vertical-align:middle helps me center the numbers inside my divs that are absolutely positioned.

Any help is appreciated.

**Html**

```
<div id='test'>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#test {
    position: relative;    
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
    width: 33.33%;
    height: 33.33%;
    text-align: center;
}

.cell:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var cell = $("<div class='cell'></div>");
var e = $('#test');
var val;
for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<3;j++) {
        val = (i*3)+(j+1);
        c = cell.clone();
        $(e).append(c);
        $(c).html(val);
        $(c).css('top',(i*33.33)+'%');
        $(c).css('left',(j*33.33)+'%');
        $(c).data('value',val);
    }
}
```

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/wB7Mk/1/

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the `line-height` equal to the height in pixels.  You can get the height with `$(height)`

```
.css('line-height', $(c).height() + 'px');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/wB7Mk/2/

Answer (score 0):

Just add one line to your CSS,

in `.cell`

```
.cell{line-height:33px;}
```

this will do, no hard work required at all :)

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/wB7Mk/3/)

if you want it dynamically add this

`$('.cell').css("line-height","33px");`

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wB7Mk/4/)

Comment: Is there a way to specify it in a relative manner? I want to do something like 33%..

Comment: You can add the jQuery Line,
`$('.cell').css("line-height","33px");` this will also do :)